# Multi level sidemenu in ionic2

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

I want to create multilevel sidemenu/ accordion inside sidemenu in ionic2. I need some help to start this.

```
Option1
 -suboption1
   -anotheroption1
   -anotheroption2
 -suboption2
Option2
Option3
```

I have found this [codepen](http://codepen.io/badpenguin/pen/MyJEvy) but this is in ionic1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-MultiLevelSideMenu)

Comment: @sebaferreras heyy thanks..Thats exactly what i needed :)